# Issue serializing data with protobuf - invalid binary stream generated (1 extra byte within message) in release version

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, protocol-buffers

I'm facing a strange issue with protobuf in C++ on Windows with Visual Studio 2017 with protobuf 3.10.0.

As I couldn't isolate the root cause yet and wasn't yet able to create a useful minimal sample code sample I could share, I'm trying to explain the issue as good as I can. My goal here is to get some input if anyone faced the same or similar issue to get an idea on how to debug down the issue. Looking for any helpful ideas.

I've added protocol buffers for serialization to a complex, existing project. This worked very well so far.

But just lately we started to see an issue that the serialized streams could not be deserialized again by the same executables.

**The issue:** We can't de-serialize a protbuf stream we serialized before (doesn't occur always, but seems to be repeatable for certain data).

Analyzing the serialized protbuf raw stream, it looks there are single extra-bytes (typically `0xCD` ...) in the protobuf stream, usually within the binary representation of single fields (between the length and the content of a field). The size of messages and fields seem to be "correct" (if the malicious extra-byte wouldn't be present).

There are **some clues that seem to indicate this is a problem with VS2017 C++ compiler's optimizations**:

- Our build server and most of our developer's PCs run VS 2017 **Vers. 15.9.x**. The problem can occur in executables built on those machines. It started to occur when moved to a new build server with 15.9.x versions.
- I've got a PC that still is on VS 2017 **V.15.7.6**; we were unable so far to expose the problem on executables build on that PC.
- We were unable to reproduce the issue on any **debug** builds so far.

We encountered either the same or a very similar issue earlier with protobuf 3.5.1 (during serialization, protobuf threw a FatalException indicating that the predicted size doesn't match the stream lengths), also only present in release versions with the VS2017 toolchain version in question, but that temporarily went away when we switched to protobuf 3.10.0. With 3.10.0, it looks like the checks that caused the FatalException have been removed (I know the parsers/serializer has been changed in 3.10.0) and the FatalException isn't thrown anymore. The issue occurs in less situations, too.

Also, the data we have in our messages seem to play a role on whether or not the issue occurs.

It's a bit hard to debug or isolate the issue to a form where I could really pinpoint a certain optimization or piece of code as the culprit. Trying to recreate the issue in what seems to be "minimal working samples" that should exposre the issue failed so far. I can't see anything suspcious in the protobuf code, either. I'm running out of ideas and wanted to know if anybody out there is facing similar issues or has any ideas what next steps I could take. Yes, I searched the internet, but I found NOTHING on the issue so far. If I can post more information on the issue (other than: the source code ...), please let me know.

Info:

- Protocol buffers is build from source, using cmake and the same VS2017 toolchain used to build the main project.
- It's statically linked into the main application.
- C++ runtime in external dll (/MD) for both the protobuf library and the main project.
- protobuf compiler (protoc) used to generate the code is from the same build as the protobuf libs linked into the project and the header files compiled against.
- We are not simultaneously accesing the protobuf message object to be serialized from other threads.

Comment: The Debug runtime uses 0xCD to fill uninitialized memory (ie what you get back from `new` or `malloc`. Are you properly initializing all input to the protobuffer construction?

Comment: I know. But this issue isn't occuring in a debug build. I assume that protobuf initializes it's internal array buffer with 0xCD, too. What exactly do you mean with "all input to the protobuffer construction"? Do I set all fields in the message? No! I leave some at default values. That shouldn't cause any issues AFAIK, though.

Comment: It will if you pass it a `char*` that is not properly terminated or filled.

Comment: On re-reading the questions: changing compilers or compiler optimization levels is *exactly* the kind of thing that reveals undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, if the issue is reproducible, have you stepped through the protobuf writing logic?

Comment: > Also, if the issue is reproducible, have you stepped through the protobuf writing logic? -- That's the point, I can't reproduce it in a way that I could step it through with a debugger yet. > if you pass it char* ... -- I'm only passing std::string to protobuf bytes and string fields. The field's contents itself are OK. The failure itself happens on serializing int or bool fields - between the length and content, as I said. This is not a problem with any buffers I'm passing to the protbuf API.

Comment: Maybe for clarity - on your comments regarding passing char* with uninitialized/inproper initialized content: The protobuf raw bin stream that is serialized is INVALID, it's not that UNEXPECTED DATA is serialized...